# How to opt out Task Bar Button & Display System Tray Icon

Tags: c#, winforms, notifications, taskbar, system-tray

How can I hide my VC# applications task bar button and show a system tray icon instead. Then, when I have the icon, how to display notifications like FDM or Windows Update etc, and add right click menu to the icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. On your form set `ShowInTaskbar` to false.
2. Use a control called `NotifyIcon` to add icons to the system tray. It also has an handy [ShowBalloonTip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160065.aspx) method.

Answer (score 2):

The [NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx) class creates an icon in the system tray.  As that page indicates, you can create a ContextMenu, which will appear when the user right clicks.

NotifyIcon includes "BalloonTip" properties that can be used to display the messages you're referring to.  This example is from the MSDN documentation.

```
notifyIcon1.Icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Application.ExecutablePath);
notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
notifyIcon1.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Error;
notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Delayed Write Failed";
notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "Some of your data has been lost.";
notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(0);
```

As @Kobi says, you also want to set your form's ShowInTaskbar property to false.